# Insert Multiple One to Many data to SQL 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have 2 tables:

```
  Object      
| id          | - AUTO IDENTITY
| Title       |
| property_id | - FK_Object_To_Property

  Property
| id          | - AUTO IDENTITY
| Name        |
| Value       |
```

Migrating from another DB i need to insert a big count of Objects each has many properties.
I don't want to insert one by one all obejcts as this is very slow. how can i insert all objects and get all ID to associate with Properties?

Comment: Unless I misunderstand you, it sounds like you want an `INSERT ...SELECT ...` statement with the IDENTITY_INSERT option on?

Comment: I have 1 million of Objects with 100-1000 properties each. I need to insert all these records to DB. it will be better to avoid manual IDENTITY